# Archiving Large Table (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very large table being filled with about 100s of million records each quarter.

I manually move data from the existing table to another database using [this script](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/gradually-deleting-data-in-sql-server/), to minimize the backup size, and to off load the production database when performing queries.

Is there any better way, for example, some scheduled script that will move data from the production database to some other database and then delete the records from the source database every day or week efficiently?

Note that my log file is growing rapidly due to the high number of INSERTs into this table, also when I move data to the archive database, DELETEs will be logged.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding partitioning?  This appears to be a perfect use case.  I'm no SQLServer partitioning expert, so I'll let someone else jump in on the particulars, but with this kind of size, swapping partitions out seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me recap the requirements:

1. reduce the backup size
2. reduce the number of records in the database by archiving
3. archive the data without excessive logging

In order to reduce the backup size, you'll need to move the data into a different database.

As far as logging goes, you'll want to look over the [rules of minimal logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx) and make sure that you are following them. Make sure that the recovery model of the database you are inserting into is in the simple or bulk-logged recovery model.

For inserting the archived data, you want to disable non-clustereds (and rebuild them after the insert has completed), utilize trace flag 610 if there is a clustered index, and put a table lock on the destination table. There are many more rules in the link that you'll want to check off, but these are the basics.

There is no minimal logging for deletes, but you can minimize log file growth by deleting in chunks with the top clause. The basic idea is (switch to simple recovery model for the duration of the delete to limit file growth):

```
SELECT NULL;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

     DELETE TOP (50000) FROM TABLE WHERE Condition = TRUE;
```

Adjust the top number to adjust how much logging per delete is done. You'll also want to make sure the predicate condition is correct so that you only delete what you intend to. This will delete 50000, then if a rowcount is returned, it will repeat until the rowcount returned is 0.

If you really want minimal logging for everything, you can partition the source table by week, create a clone of the source table (on the same partition function and identical indexing structure), switch the partition from the source table to the cloned table, insert from the cloned table to the archive table, then truncate the cloned table. The advantage of this is a truncate rather than a delete. The disadvantage is that it's much more complicated to setup, maintain, and query (you get one heap or b-tree per partition, so if all queries don't utilize partition elimination, a clustered index/table scan would have to scan multiple b-trees/heaps instead of just one).

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using SSIS to do this. I use SSIS to do the archiving and the backup in an order. You can also use the same script in the tsql task and schedule it using the agent. Or you can just use the agent and past the script into it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Table partitioning instead of moving data

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580(v=sql.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(v=sql.90).aspx

For moving data periodically you could use SQL Server Job scheduling functionality to run a SSIS package.

Maybe Data Transformation Services (DTS) could be used too.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning, definitely. It will remove the need of a new database. Good example [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/)

If you dont want to change your architecture, I suggest using SSIS to move the data rather than scripts

Comment: I like partitioning for archival and do think it is part of the solution, but this isn't going to reduce the backup size which is one of the OPs requirements.